# Identifying GET or POST request in MVC (Razor) Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a code to display success or error toast in JavaScript when MVC View is submitted.
Below is the code.

**View (JavaScript)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //first check model is in edit mode of submit mode?????
    var _model = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model));
    if(_model != null){
        if(_model.ID > 0)
        {
            //Show Success Toast
        }
        else
        {
            //Show Error Toast                
        }
    }
});
```

when successful form submitted and returned view with model then Model ID will be populated and logic is implemented to detect model id is > 0. Now in controller.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? ID)
    {
        if (ID != null)
            return View(new Repository().GetDataByID(ID));
        else
            return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Data _data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            new Repository().AddData(_data);
        return View(_data);
    }
```

***Problem Statement***

1. Logic is working fine when adding new data and view is submitted successfully and toast is displayed. But problem is when editing existing data the logic treats as successfully submission and toast is displayed for success. Because the Model ID is > 0.
2. How can I determine either it is GET request (Editing an existing data) or post request and display toast message accordingly.?
3. ***I dont want to use viewBag or any other flag in model. Can it be done in JavaScript?***

Comment: Let's see .. when using SerializeObject it will always interpret it as submit, if what you are looking for is to get a message like "successful update",
I recommend that you do an editing function when sending the request, perform a search for the ID that belongs to that record, if it exists then update the data because you only use AddData.